# How to make Thunderbird stop during email download?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I finally moved my old Outlook Express stuff to Thunderbird, and am downloading all emails stored on POP3 server.

But I don't want Thunderbird to download them all at once. I want 20 at a time, so I can see them and delete junk ones and move remaining to their proper folders before downloading more.

I can't find a button to stop downloading. Once I make Thunderbird download emails, it just keeps downloading and the only way I found to stop it is closing it.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: There are other questions about Thunderbird here. Vote to close them all then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: while the specific counts are not possible, you can switch back and forth between offline/not offline, but it's a pain, requires confirm click.

Otherwise:
Download all emails. Use spam emails to train your thunderbird spam filters once all the emails have downloaded. Start at the beginning of the list. It's a one time operation, don't overthink it. As you assign 'junk' status to emails, you can rerun the spam filters on the inbox until it's properly trained, and most of the subsequent emails will get moved to the Junk folder automatically after you've created a decent set of spam samples. If you give the junk filter a few hundred samples it will be pretty accurate. Check junk folder for false positives, mark not junk, repeat until it's good. Much less work than doing it 20 emails at a time.

Thunderbird's builtin spam filters are quite good once properly trained.

When viewing (including preview mode) spam emails, make sure that third party image view is disabled, otherwise you will be validating your email address in the spammer email databases (they use often images or links with unique id's in them that when loaded or clicked simply validate your email address as current). Ideally disable all html viewing and view in text mode only, no html.

As with training your spam filters, the same applies to email rules/filters, which are even easier to create and run.

Create filters that move the emails to the desired folders after you make the folders, and after you create each filter, run the filters on the inbox again.

Because the user is fairly stubborn in this case, here's the basics when interacting with a new piece of software:

1. Check to see if the desired feature that another similar program has is supported. If it isn't, and you're sure you didn't just miss it, the developers don't care about that feature, or the feature is not technically possible due to how the software is constructed. The users in general also don't care about that feature, otherwise someone would have filed an issue, and others would have piled on over time, until the devs got tired of that issue and made it happen. In this case, we can assume none of that happened.
2. Check to see if the program supports extensions of some kind. Thunderbird does, so look for an extension that extends the features of the software to do what you want. If nobody wrote this extension, this means that no person capable of programming cares about that feature, in most cases, or, that the software itself doesn't support it internally.
3. check on a site like here to make sure you didn't miss anything, and that actually that feature does exist somewhere somehow. If your results are negative again, that's about the end of the road in the quest for that personal favorite feature.
4. Check to see if there is another way that sort of emulates what you want. In this case, for example, you can go offline/online though it takes a few steps each time, and certainly isn't a feature intended to do what the OP asked, but it can be used in this way crudely.

If neither 1 nor 2 show support for the desired feature, decide how important that feature was to you. If it is very important, research the core codebase and see if you can extend it via extension to support the feature, or hire someone to write the extension for you, and maintain it over years, or don't use the software.

Now, if after these checks, you find that not one single person in the world cared enough to add support for the feature, it means there's not a whole lot of demand for it, and certainly no demand from the free software developers who in the case of thunderbird, wrote it, and its extensions, and probably not from the users either, which is a lot of people globally in this case.

Once you determine that there was and is no demand for the feature, move on to something more productive, and stop complaining that the feature that apparently nobody ever was willing to take the time to implement isn't implemented, it means nobody cared enough to do it, that's all. Complaining here about that won't change that fact.

If you have decided to use the new software anyway, then adjust your workflow to the fact that the desired feature is not going to be part of your life anymore. This is also known as being an adult in some societies.

Other similar things that don't support everything that another similar software does:

1. gimp does not support everything photoshop does
2. windows does not support everything gnu/linux does
3. gnu/linux does not support everything that windows does
4. claws mail does not support everything thunderbird does
5. thunderbird and outlook express are different pieces of software that are similar in function but internally quite unrelated, they don't even use the same mail storage format, for example.
6. Mac OSX is different from GNU/Linux, FreeBSD (although internally it's got some similarities), and Windows.
7. Windows 98 is different from Windows 2000 which is different from Windows XP which is different from Vista which is different from Windows 7 which is different from 8 and 8.1 which is different from Windows 10.
8. Outlook is different from every email client known to man and woman alike. As is its mail storage format. Be very glad you are not trying to find software that is similar, you'd be out of luck, since nobody else is crazy enough to produce such a mess.

And so on. The software I write does similar things to other software, but is different, quite different, from all of them. This is why people use it and like it. If it were the same, there would be no reason to use it. If someone posts an issue asking for a feature a similar but different piece of software has, I'd think: Ok, is it a good idea? Does it meet a valid need? If so, is it hard? Is it possible at all (the other software may not even be right for example)? Is it possible within my software's framework? Did I receive a patch (always a great way to motive a developer)? If the first condition, it being a good idea, was never met, then you can forget about the rest, they are irrelevant.

I agree this isn't a great stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking. I use MailWasher to handle spam. What I want is to download emails 20 by 20 to sort them into folders, I don't wanna download them all at once.

Comment: See my updated response. You want email filters. Same deal, download all emails, create then apply filters. Repeat until done. You're trying to use manual techniques to do something thunderbird is designed to do automatically, which is why you aren't finding any answers, the problem doesn't exist unless you decide to not use thunderbirds native features. Also, there's no difference between downloading 20 at a time and doing blocks of 20 emails at a time after downloading all the emails  in terms of the desired outcome, which is another reason there's no point to what you want to do.

Comment: lol yes I can use filters to move email. But really, it's the user who must dictate how to use a software, not the dev. I don't wanna download hundreds of emails and let Thunderbird "handle it for me", I just wanna download some emails and not all of them. I'm doing deep cleaning on them on MailWasher, I clean some and download them, then clean some more. All I want is to download 20 at a time, I don't wanna do on Thunderbird the job I do on MailWasher.

Comment: Is it rly not possible to stop a mail download once it started other than closing Thunderbird? It's a very basic feature on Outlook Express, that's around since... Win98?

Comment: Outlook express stored its emails one at a time, as files, one per email, if I remember right. Every piece of software makes decisions on how to do things. If you wanted your thunderbird to store emails as single files, you'd be out of luck. If you insist on maintaining 100% feature parity between two different pieces of software, that's usually an indication you should stick to the original piece of software, which does what you apparently want it to do. If you fight against the software you've picked, you'll always be unhappy and frustrated. I dumped oe 15 years ago roughly, glad I did.

Comment: I suggest you adapt yourself to what the software is good at, which is, incidentally, much better than OE ever is or was. If this makes you unhappy, then stick with OE, which I think isn't even developed anymore (?). No idea why you're attached to mailwasher, it's not necessary, thunderbird already does that stuff natively, so again, you're fighting against thunderbird while insisting it be like OE+mailwasher, so it appears what you actually wanted all along was OE+mailwasher. I can point to unix features that have been around since, what, 1972? that Windows has NEVER had, nor will ever.

Comment: Lizardx, you're trying to push me into stuff completely different from what I asked here. I said "I have 200 email on my POP3 server, I wanna Thunderbird to download 20 of them and stop leaving 180 there", you could have just answered that Thunderbird doesn't support stopping once started downloading emails and the only work around is to close the whole app, or point me a better solution.

Comment: I'm just replacing OE for Thunderbird. I use MailWasher way more often and I intend to keep using it. Actually I haven't used OE for almost 3 years and I use MailWasher every day. I *don't* wanna replace MailWasher for Thunderbird, and I *didn't* ask how to do MailWasher's features in Thunderbird. I have almost 10 active email accounts and receive A LOT of spam every day. I don't wanna have Thunderbird handing spam neither automatically moving email to folders.

Comment: Also, there are email I need stored for a while than I can delete them, so I don't want them downloaded to mail client and stored. I intend to download emails only a few months old, and leave newer emails laying on server waiting for deeper cleaning and then definitive persistence on mail client. All that requires me to download a few emails and stop it. MailWashers works fine for me and I don't wanna drop it, and I doubt Thunderbird does its job as good as it does. Just its table is the best I've ever seen in any app, and it works great for splitting spam.